# How to exclude specific strings among list?

Tags: python, regex

I used a empty list to slice and format strings.

But I don't want to see some strings in the result.

Example: I don't want to show 'riichard' and 'canturyooo'.

How could I set something like **blacklist** to directly add into the list so that I can easily exclude the words I don't want?

Like:(Use minus(-) to exclude words)

```
words = [
    ('riich', 'rich',-'riichard',-'riicharson'),
    ('cantury', 'century',-'canturyooo'),
```

Is **Regex** the only way to exclude them?

Or is there any better way to do that?

This is my code:

```
import xlsxwriter
from functools import partial


def x_in_y(word, inner):
    return inner in word


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

words = [
    ('riich', 'rich'),
    ('cantury', 'century'),
]
sentence = [
    'riichard dweqrerwr',
    'he is very riich',
    'this is 21st cantury',
    'canturyooo mankind',
]

row = 0

red = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'red'})
black = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'black'})

for wrong, correct in words:
    filtered_names = filter(partial(x_in_y, inner=wrong), sentence)
    next_elem = next(filtered_names, None)

    if next_elem:
        worksheet.write(row, 0, f"Typo: {wrong} 'should be {correct}'")
        row += 1
        while next_elem:
            if len(next_elem) == len(wrong):
                worksheet.write(row, 0, next_elem, red)
            else:
                slices = []
                startIndex = 0
                index = next_elem.find(wrong)
                while index != -1:
                    if next_elem[startIndex: index]:
                        slices.append(black)
                        slices.append(next_elem[startIndex: index])
                    slices.append(red)
                    slices.append(next_elem[index: index + len(wrong)])
                    startIndex = index + len(wrong)
                    index = next_elem.find(wrong, startIndex)

                if next_elem[startIndex:]:
                    slices.append(black)
                    slices.append(next_elem[startIndex:])

                worksheet.write_rich_string(row, 0, *slices)
            row += 1
            next_elem = next(filtered_names, None)
workbook.close()
```

Result:

[image]

I hope it may look like:

[image]

Comment: Use can use if condition with continue to skip certain strings

Comment: I have tried that. But it would be quite inconvenient if I want to exclude many words. I hope it can be more manageable like tuple or list.

Comment: If word in [list of words], use something like this

Comment: ok. thanks...... I tried that but the program just keep running and won't stop. but thanks...